# Testing subscriptions for Angular 8 ngOnInit

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to learn angular unit testing with Karma and Jasmine.

My problem is that when I try to test the component is created, I get: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'
Because I have subscriptions in the ngOnInit() and I dont know how to test subscriptions inside a method.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you observable subscribed on the lifecycle on init are the input of your component, so you have to set this value in your test.

```
it('should create', () => {
    // Here you have to set every input used on your ngOnInit()
    component.cast = new Observable((observer) => { observer.next(true); });
    component.cast2 = new Observable((observer) => { observer.next(true); });
    component.cast3 = new Observable((observer) => { observer.next('test'); });
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Its working now :) So much thanks I'm so noob with unit testing.